# how to convert a binary file into a text readable file using java

Tags: java, file, text, binary

I'm trying to convert a binary content of a file to a readable text file using a java code.
This is the code used so far which doesn't give a readable text content:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Sami\\Desktop\\example-trace");

    int ch;
    StringBuffer strContent = new StringBuffer("");
        FileInputStream fin = null;


  fin = new FileInputStream(file);

  while( (ch = fin.read()) != -1)
    strContent.append((char)ch);
     fin.close();

         System.out.println(strContent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

edit: added version to read 32bit binary integers...

@wang7x was right, encoding is important.
It turns out you don't have any TEXT encoding at all, it looks more like a series of binary 32 bit integers.
My first version (Foo.java, way below now) does print out exactly what you said.  The *intent* of Foo.java is to scan a file and print out some text.

Seeing the file helps - a lot ( Please start with that + expected output next time :-) ).

The next version (Bar.java, not so far below) attempts to extract 32 bit binary integers.

So... how does this look for partial output?  The values I'm seeing for "target" matched what you posted in your comment.
Just out of idle curiosity, what is generating your binary data?

```
     === begin Bar.java sample output ===
     1:   curByte=  0   0x00   target.1=0x00000000
     2:   curByte=  0   0x00   target.2=0x00000000
     3:   curByte= 22   0x16   target.3=0x00000016
     4:   curByte=108   0x6c   target.4=0x0000166c
      : target= 5740 0x0000166c
     5:   curByte=  0   0x00   target.1=0x00000000
     6:   curByte=  0   0x00   target.2=0x00000000
     7:   curByte=  3   0x03   target.3=0x00000003
     8:   curByte=232   0xe8   target.4=0x000003e8
      : target= 1000 0x000003e8
     9:   curByte=  0   0x00   target.1=0x00000000
    10:   curByte=  0   0x00   target.2=0x00000000
    11:   curByte= 30   0x1e   target.3=0x0000001e
    12:   curByte= 56   0x38   target.4=0x00001e38
      : target= 7736 0x00001e38
    13:   curByte=  0   0x00   target.1=0x00000000
    14:   curByte=  0   0x00   target.2=0x00000000
    15:   curByte=  1   0x01   target.3=0x00000001
    16:   curByte=244   0xf4   target.4=0x000001f4
      : target=  500 0x000001f4
    17:   curByte=  0   0x00   target.1=0x00000000
    18:   curByte=  6   0x06   target.2=0x00000006
    19:   curByte=179   0xb3   target.3=0x000006b3
    20:   curByte=146   0x92   target.4=0x0006b392
      : target=439186 0x0006b392
...etc...
 62909:   curByte=  0   0x00   target.1=0x00000000
 62910:   curByte=  0   0x00   target.2=0x00000000
 62911:   curByte=  3   0x03   target.3=0x00000003
 62912:   curByte=232   0xe8   target.4=0x000003e8
      : target= 1000 0x000003e8
 62913:   curByte=  0   0x00   target.1=0x00000000
 62914:   curByte=  0   0x00   target.2=0x00000000
 62915:   curByte= 21   0x15   target.3=0x00000015
 62916:   curByte=150   0x96   target.4=0x00001596
      : target= 5526 0x00001596
 62917:   curByte=  0   0x00   target.1=0x00000000
 62918:   curByte=  0   0x00   target.2=0x00000000
 62919:   curByte=  2   0x02   target.3=0x00000002
 62920:   curByte=238   0xee   target.4=0x000002ee
      : target=  750 0x000002ee
total bytes: 62920
total targets: 15730
minTarget: 250
maxTarget: 993461
     === end Bar.java sample output ===
```

About the program, Bar.java, the line printing the "cureByte=...." stuff is more or less for debugging and understanding; comment that out and you should have a start.

You may also want to search on reading binary data in Java - I'm sure there are more efficient ways to assemble integers in Java.  Please consider this to be just ideas for further research on your part.
Also note this assumes everything is just a 32bit unsigned integers, I will leave it to you to work out whether or not you may have to handle negative (signed) values.

Based on the part of the program that displays the min & max, the larget values in the sample you posted was 993,461.
That assembles "target" like so... note how target.1 is empty (all zeros), target.2 picks up the 0xF (fifteen in decimal), then bit pattern in target continues to shift left until all of the bytes are binary-or'ed onto the end.

```
=== largest value found in sample data ===
 44217:   curByte=  0   0x00   target.1=0x00000000
 44218:   curByte= 15   0x0f   target.2=0x0000000f
 44219:   curByte= 40   0x28   target.3=0x00000f28
 44220:   curByte=181   0xb5   target.4=0x000f28b5
      : target=993461 0x000f28b5


=== begin Bar.java ===
import java.io.*;

public class Bar {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      File file = new File("example-trace");  // change to whatever you want for input.

      int curByte; // current byte - we'll read one byte at a time.

      FileInputStream fin = fin = new FileInputStream(file);

      int totalByteCnt = 0;
      int byteCnt = 0; // track up to 4 bytes per integer.
      long target = 0;
      int targetCnt = 0; // track how many targets we are able to construct.
      long minTarget = 0;
      long maxTarget = 0;

      int cutoff = -1; // for testing, set to -1 for all input.
      while( (curByte = fin.read()) != -1) {
         ++totalByteCnt;

         ++byteCnt;
         target <<= 8; // left-shift our target 8 bytes.
         target |= curByte; // binary-or to apply byte.
         System.out.printf("%6d:   curByte=%3d   0x%02x   target.%d=0x%08x\n"
            ,totalByteCnt
            , curByte
            , curByte
            , byteCnt
            , target );

         if( byteCnt == 4 ) {
            ++targetCnt;
            System.out.printf("%6s: target=%5d 0x%08x\n", "", target, target );
            byteCnt = 0;
            // just for fun track our minimum & maximum values.
            if( targetCnt == 1 ) minTarget = maxTarget = target;
            if( target < minTarget ) minTarget = target;
            if( target > maxTarget ) maxTarget = target;
            target=0;
         }

         if( cutoff != -1 && totalByteCnt >= cutoff ) {
            System.out.println("debug: Hit cutoff="+cutoff);
            break;
         }
      }
      fin.close();
      System.out.println("total bytes: "+totalByteCnt);
      System.out.println("total targets: "+targetCnt);
      if( byteCnt != 0 ) {
         System.out.println("warning: only found "+byteCnt+" bytes of last target, incomplete value at byte offset "+totalByteCnt);
      }
      System.out.println("minTarget: "+minTarget);
      System.out.println("maxTarget: "+maxTarget);
   }

}
=== end Bar.java ===
```

=== ORIGINAL ====

The hardest part of your problem may be defining what you mean by "readable".
Really, it does.. I'm not trying to give you a hard time about something "obviously easy".  Does "readable" mean...

Just ascii A-Z ?

All of Unicode?

Everything but control-bit characters?

Only sequences of 2+ letters and/or digits?

So, the following code has a guess in it: see the IF statement inside of the while loop.

```
if( Character.isLetter(ch)
||  Character.isDigit(ch)
||  Character.isSpaceChar(ch)
```

Your results will vary, *a lot*, depending on the logic you use to decide if something is "readable".

(btw, this would have been a little easier to answer if you posted an example of what your input consists of, along with what you want to see.  Though I kind of understand the part about how it has 'binary content' that makes it difficult to post an example of :-)  )

Also... it may already be written (if you were on linux or unix instead of windows I would refer you the the utilities **strings** and **hexdump**).

Suppose we have the following file "Foo.java" - we will use it for testing since you didn't post one of your own:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Foo {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      File file = new File("Foo.java");  // change to whatever you want for input.

      int ch;
      StringBuffer strContent = new StringBuffer("");
      // Instead of a string buffer you might want to create an
      //  output file to hold strContent.
      // strContent is probably going to be... messy :-)


      FileInputStream fin = fin = new FileInputStream(file);

      int charCnt = 0;
      int readableCnt = 0;
      int cutoff = 1000; // for testing, set to -1 for all input.
      while( (ch = fin.read()) != -1) {
         ++charCnt;
         if( cutoff != -1 && charCnt >= cutoff ) {
            System.out.println("debug: Hit cutoff="+cutoff);
            break;
         }
         char readable = '.'; // default to smth for not-so-readable; replace w/your favorite char here.
         // lots of different ways to test this.
         // If your data is relatively simple, you might want to define
         // "readable" as anything from ascii space through newline.
         if( Character.isLetter(ch)
         ||  Character.isDigit(ch)
         ||  Character.isSpaceChar(ch)
         ) {
            strContent.append((char)ch);
            readable = (char)ch;
            ++readableCnt;
         } else {
            // looks like non-readable.
            // not much to do here.
         }
         System.out.printf("%6d: ch=%04d 0x%04x %c\n", charCnt, ch, ch, readable);
      }
      fin.close();
      System.out.println("total chars: "+charCnt);
      System.out.println("readable chars: "+readableCnt);
      System.out.println("\n--- BEGIN READABLE STUFF---");
      System.out.println(strContent);
      System.out.println("\n--- END BEGIN READABLE STUFF---");
   }

}
```

Here is the tail end of the example output:

```
--- begin output from Foo.java ---
   995: ch=0101 0x0065 e
   996: ch=0108 0x006c l
   997: ch=0097 0x0061 a
   998: ch=0116 0x0074 t
   999: ch=0105 0x0069 i
debug: Hit cutoff=1000
total chars: 1000
readable chars: 862

--- BEGIN READABLE STUFF---
import javaiopublic class Foo    public static void mainString args throws IOException       File file  new FileFoojava   change to whatever you want for input            int ch      StringBuffer strContent  new StringBuffer       Instead of a string buffer you might want to create an        output file to hold strContent       strContent is probably going to be messy       FileInputStream fin  fin  new FileInputStreamfile            int charCnt  0      int readableCnt  0      int cutoff  1000  for testing set to 1 for all input      while ch  finread  1          charCnt         if cutoff  1  charCnt  cutoff              Systemoutprintlndebug Hit cutoffcutoff            break                  char readable    default to smth for notsoreadable replace wyour favorite char here          lots of different ways to test this          If your data is relati

--- END BEGIN READABLE STUFF---
--- end output from Foo.java ---
```

And again, recompiled to run on the Foo.class file (instead of the *.java file):

```
--- begin output from Foo.class ---
   992: ch=0067 0x0043 C
   993: ch=0104 0x0068 h
   994: ch=0097 0x0061 a
   995: ch=0114 0x0072 r
   996: ch=0097 0x0061 a
   997: ch=0099 0x0063 c
   998: ch=0116 0x0074 t
   999: ch=0101 0x0065 e
debug: Hit cutoff=1000
total chars: 1000
readable chars: 589

--- BEGIN READABLE STUFF---
Êþº4t2345675892ABCDEDFDGHIJKLDMBNOPQRBSTUinitVCodeLineNumberTablemainLjavalangStringVStackMapTableV368ExceptionsWSourceFileFoojavajavaioFileFooclassXjavalangStringBufferjavaioFileInputStreamYZjavalangStringBuilderdebug Hit cutoffabcdeXfghihjhk6d ch04d 0x04x cjavalangObjectlmnmopqrtotal chars readable chars  BEGIN READABLE STUFFes  END BEGIN READABLE STUFFFooLjavalangStringjavaioIOExceptionLjavalangStringVLjavaioFileVreadIjavalangSystemoutLjavaioPrintStreamappendLjavalangStringLjavalangStringBuilderILjavalangStringBuildertoStringLjavalangStringjavaioPrintStreamprintlnjavalangCharacte

--- END BEGIN READABLE STUFF---

--- end output from Foo.class ---
```

Comment: actually here is the file: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=510F2449F1B18E46!16380&authkey=!AHiblC2d2s0hkGk&ithint=file%2c

Comment: what i had when i executed your code is:  1: ch=0000 0x0000 .
     2: ch=0000 0x0000 .
     3: ch=0022 0x0016 .
     4: ch=0108 0x006c l
     5: ch=0000 0x0000 .
     6: ch=0000 0x0000 .
     7: ch=0003 0x0003 .
     8: ch=0232 0x0

Comment: But probably this is not the correct decoding since i'm meant to find this as beginning of file: 5740, 1000
7736, 500
439186, 1000
42907, 1000
5789, 1000
281320, 1000

Comment: ahh... seeing the data helps.  Helps a  lot :-)  Answer edited accordingly.

Comment: yea, that's exactly what i was looking for, you're my champion man. Actually this file is a trace file used in ns2. The next step i'm gonna pass through is to store the "target" data is a file than to modify it according to my needs and finally to get it back to binary format. Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Writing "human readable" is easy enough, easiest way for you might be to modify the output (various prints) of Bar.java then run it as "java Bar > myns2.txt" so you can edit it with notepad or whatever.  Going the other way isn't too bad.  Imagine 'source', like 'target' bout in reverse.  You can do 'source = Integer.parseInt( mystring ); int byte4 = source & 0xFF000000; int byte3 = source & 0x00FF000; etc. then print the bytes to your output file.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file content into a `byte[]` buffer,then convert the buffer into a `String`, you need to specify the encoding like `UTF-8`.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int n = fin.read(buffer);
strContent.append(new String(buffer,0,n,"UTF-8"));
```

if you do know the binary file is a text file, use `FileReader` instead of `FileInputStream`

Comment: I tried to do that but it seems that it's not the correct encoding, it gives some non readable staff, actually this is the file i'm trying to convert: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=510F2449F1B18E46!16380&authkey=!AHiblC2d2s0hkGk&ithint=file%2c

Comment: I tried every charset in `Charset.availableCharsets()`,none of them works.This file may not be written as text file,you need to know which way the file was written @Vladimir90